# which bash is executing?

Tags: bash, shell

I think I have configured bash as shell, but why is this happening?

My shell is bash:

```
# ls -al `which sh`
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 12 03:25 /bin/sh -> bash
```

Error executing a script with sh

```
# sh ubuntu/util.sh
  ubuntu/util.sh: line 32: `test-build-release': not a valid identifier
```

No error from bash

```
# bash ubuntu/util.sh
```

Comment: can you post your `until.sh`

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/ubuntu/util.sh

Comment: Couldn't you have made the file executable (`chmod +x util.sh`) and then run it with `./util.sh`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is running the bash executable you expect, but your shell is not simply bash; it is bash running in POSIX `sh` compatibility mode. It does this by looking at the command name it was invoked as, and if that is `sh`, then it automatically activates POSIX mode. It does a very terrible job at this, and should not be fully relied on for testing POSIX `sh` compatible scripts, but it should considerably restrict allowed syntax.

> #### --posix
>
> Change the behavior of bash where the default operation differs from the POSIX standard to match the standard (posix mode). 
>   See SEE ALSO below for a reference to a document that details how posix mode affects bash's behavior.

And from http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/POSIX :

> Starting Bash with the `--posix` command-line option or executing `set
>   -o posix` while Bash is running will cause Bash to conform more closely to the POSIX standard by changing the behavior to match that
>   specified by POSIX in areas where the Bash default differs.
>
> When invoked as `sh`, Bash enters POSIX mode after reading the startup
>   files.

Comment: Thank you, that should be the explanation. I am not running this script directly, I am trying to install Kubernetes and after a lot of work it fails with 'not a valid identifier' error. Can I switch Posix off globally?

Comment: not sure on a clean solution... but for a dirty hack, remove sh, replace it with a shell script that runs `bash "$@"; exit $?`

Comment: and I must add that I find this funny...because it's probably just like I said "should not be fully relied on for testing POSIX"... the author of your script probably only tested with bash, not sh, and not the same version of it as you are using. :)

Comment: @AssenKolov **issue:** while "-" used in function is fine for bash, it is not for sh, see line number 32

Comment: This sounds genius to me :-) I can't right now but will let you know after I do.

Comment: and if that fails be sure to try fixing what @Rahul pointed out... in the script you are running, they are declaring a function `test-build-release()` and that's not valid, so try renaming it, eg. to `testbuildrelease()` in declaration and all calls; or in the sh wrapper script, there's a chance you have to scan for and remove `--posix`

Comment: @Rahul: this issue is the whole reason to investigate how to exclude sh (or POSIX mode, as I understand from @Peter) from running scripts.

Comment: kubernetes is more than a few lines of script, have a look at the script I am actually starting that eventually fails in utils.sh: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/kube-up.sh Just changing the name of this method will not bring me far. I could either fix the bugs in kubernetes scripts (and get the fix merged to master, or maintain a local copy), or make sure I run them without posix mode.

Comment: The script is executed as ssh otheruser@localhost " ... source utils.sh ..." what makes it posix style?

Comment: @AssenKolov it is posix mode if they used --posix (probably not) or they ran it as "sh" because either it's the user's shell and they didn't set one (which is what source does, ignoring the shebang), or the shebang said it, or they ran "sh somescript" and then maybe that one used source.